# Why is my component throwing a "too many re-renders" error?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, infinite-loop

Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

I couldn't find where the loop is, I managed to check if the states are different from "null" I could only render the graph and avoid the error, but it persists, could someone help me?..

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Chart } from "react-google-charts";

export const StatusChart = (pokemon) => {
  const [hp, setHp] = useState(null);
  const [attack, setAttack] = useState(null);
  const [defense, setDefense] = useState(null);
  const [specialAtack, setSpecialAtack] = useState(null);
  const [specialDefese, setSpecialDefese] = useState(null);
  const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(null);

  console.log(
    pokemon.pokemon.map((e) => {
      console.log(e.base_stat);
      switch (e.stat.name) {
        case "hp":
          setHp(e.base_stat);
          break;
        case "attack":
          setAttack(e.base_stat);
          break;
        case "defense":
          setDefense(e.base_stat);
          break;
        case "special-attack":
          setSpecialAtack(e.base_stat);
          break;
        case "special-defense":
          setSpecialDefese(e.base_stat);
          break;
        case "speed":
          setSpeed(e.base_stat);
          break;
      }
    })
  );

  const data = [
    ["Status", "Value", { role: "style" }],
    ["HP", hp, "red"],
    ["Atack", attack, "orange"],
    ["Defese", defense, "green"],
    ["Special Atack", specialAtack, "gold"],
    ["Special Defense", specialDefese, "purple"],
    ["Speed", speed, "blue"],
  ];

  return (
    <>
      {hp ||
      attack ||
      defense ||
      specialAtack ||
      specialDefese ||
      speed === null ? null : (
        <Chart
          chartType="ColumnChart"
          width="100%"
          height="300px"
          data={data}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

> Github link:
> *https://github.com/yjdutra/pokedex-pokeapi*

Comment: You seem to be logging a logger.

Comment: All questions and answers on the main Stack Overflow site are [required to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/205114).  For help in Portuguese,  try [pt.so], but be sure to follow their [content guidelines](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure an on-topic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This console.log with a map inside is doing many setStates at the same time, causing the UI to re-render at each "pokemon" entity that you have. This is causing the error.